# Getting fault string in SABRE HOTEL API:Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, sabre

I am getting fault string code like -Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist

Can any one help me what I am missing.

```
$OTA_HotelAvailRQ = new stdClass;
$OTA_HotelAvailRQ->AvailRequestSegment = new stdClass;
$OTA_HotelAvailRQ->AvailRequestSegment->ReturnHostCommand = true;
$OTA_HotelAvailRQ->AvailRequestSegment->TimeStamp = '2015-11-12T11:22:06';
$OTA_HotelAvailRQ->AvailRequestSegment->Version = '2.2.1';

$client = new SoapClient("http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/tpfc/OTA_HotelAvailLLS2.2.1RQ.wsdl", [
      "trace"      => 1,        
      "exceptions" => 0,        
      "cache_wsdl" => 0
]);

$client->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Auth', [
    'UserName'=>'',
    'Password'=>'',
    'SystemId'=> [
        '_'=>'DATA',
        'Param'=>'PARAM'
    ]
], false)); 

print_r( $client->OTA_HotelAvailRQ($OTA_HotelAvailRQ));
echo "<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>";
echo "<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."</p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what is the Action you are using the MessageHeader but the correct one is not OTA_HotelAvailRQ but OTA_HotelAvail**LLS**RQ

---

EDIT:

Let me start by saying that the username should only be used on the SessionCreate in order to obtain a new session, from then on you will need to use the BinarySecurityToken that is returned. That will be valid for the same environment until the session expires or it's closed with the SessionClose. Lets imagine that I have that in variable $bst.

What I have done below is not something that I could test, so there could be something wrong, plus, my php knowledge is quite limited (keep that in mind) :)

So, you need 2 main elements in the soap header, messageHeader and Security. Security being the simplest one lets start with that.

**Security:**

```
$auth = array(
    'BinarySecurityToken'=>$bst
);
$authHeader = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext','Security',$auth,false);
```

**MessageHeader:**

```
$partyId=array(
    'PartyId'=>''
);

$messageData=array(
    'Timestamp'=>date('Y-m-d')
);

$messageHeader=array(
    'ConversationId'=>'',
    'From'=>$partyId,
    'To'=>$partyId,
    'CPAId'=>'',
    'Service'=>'OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ',
    'Action'=>'OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ',
    'MessageData'=>$messageData
);

$messageHeaderHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader','MessageHeader',$messageHeader,false);
```

**Finally join them and set it:**

```
$headers=array();
$headers[]=$authHeader;
$headers[]=$messageHeaderHeader;

$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply -
when we print $client->__getFunctions() we found the all accessible method of WSDL file. Here is showing only OTA_HotelAvailRQ method.If we will try to access OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ method then you will get Error like- "This method is not a valid method for this service".

Comment: Please consider that my knowledge on PHP is very limited.
When I try to see the methods this is what I get:
>array(1) { [0]=> string(57) "OTA_HotelAvailRS OTA_HotelAvailRQ(OTA_HotelAvailRQ $body)" }
So, the OTA_HotelAvailRQ is correct for the body.

Comment: What I just realized is that soap header is "empty". The code below
$header = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Auth',$auth,false);

Should generate a header which is something like this:
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns1:Auth>
    <ns1:SystemId Param="PARAM">DATA</ns1:SystemId>
    <ns1:UserName> </ns1:UserName>
    <ns1:Password> ns1:Password>
  </ns1:Auth>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>

And this is not a valid header for Sabre, I am assuming that this is the reason it fails